# How to print digital files?

Tags: print-design

I make digital paintings and, I want to sell them to potential customers.
I usually work in sRGB mode and save the file as jpg. Is it the right way for printing to any printing service? If not, what can I do without making the paintings all over again?  Next time I make a digital painting, what color mode and save file type must I use?

I use the jpg file type because I am not specialized to export the file as pdf. How can I export my digital painting as a pdf file?

Is a psd file another option for printing to any printing service?

Also, the colors a customer will see on their monitor will not match the colors I see on my monitor and, the colors on the final print will be different. What must I say to them?
How can I fix the colors on my monitor to be printed correctly on the final print?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Many consumer-level print services prefer sRGB from jpg files. More professional concerns want specific CMYK conversions, which require a lot more precision & expertise from the customer.
sRGB leads to less confusion at consumer-level. Asking the average user to convert to CMYK would be fraught with difficulty & also many of the printing machines they use take sRGB & convert to their own profile internally.

I would suggest, as you are not working from a profiled, calibrated workflow, you send a test file to one of these print-shops & see what you get back. Choose a cheap format for your first tests, printed to photo-paper etc rather than something expensive like aluminium or canvas, that you might consider later for customers.

I have had great success from sRGB to large canvases using little more than this method to find my ideal print supplier initially. I do have a calibrated workflow, but only as far as outputting to sRGB jpg & 100% quality. I've tried larger 'pro' printers who required specific CMYK profiles for their input… & never got colours as close as I've got from consumer printers.

BTW, there is nothing you can do about someone else's screen. You just have to cross your fingers & work on getting your own output to match what *you* see, or acceptably close.
You do have to bear in mind that if you generate artwork using extremely bright RGB colours, no print process can match that.